# How to start self-hosted OWIN Web API listening to a range of ports?

Tags: azure, owin, arr

I'm running an Azure Worker Role that with self-hosted OWIN Web API
Currently, the host is initialized with a single URL like so:

```
         var options = new StartOptions(endpoint);
        _app = WebApp.Start<Startup>(options);
```

The endpoint has a port hard-coded in it.  I'd like to have it listen on a range of ports.

My real issue is as follows:

My Web API host is not getting round-robined by Azure's load balancer.  I believe this is because the default ("none") affinity setting uses SourceIP, Source Port, Target IP, Target Port, Protocol type to perform its load balancing.  However, the clients to my Web API (in the thousands) are always the same clients - they connect **every minute** to perform some operations.  Thus, these client's ports and IP's don't change.  My listening port and IP do not change since the host is hard-coded to a port.  All of the requests from these clients are getting round-robined to the same instance all the time.  I've verified this over and over and over again.  My first worker role instance gets all the traffic, as soon as 2nd instance is rebooted.  2nd instance never kicks in.

I would like to try to have my OWIN hosted Web API listen on a range of ports.  Is this the right approach?  If so, how can this be done?